# xargs: The command line for command is built up until it reaches a system-defined limit - What limit?

Tags: linux, xargs

I looked briefly at the source code of xargs in findutils 4.6.0 and saw that
'n' defines: args_per_exec
But there seems to be no default value for args_per_exec in find utils

So where is the 'system-defined limit' defined?

It's no duplicate since the question is meant as explanation for the manpage entry, not the generic question for an arbitrary command length

Comment: Are you saying with your last edit that *you* are looking for a man-page explanation of args_per_exec? The 'looked briefly at the source code" is misleading in that regard, as then I'd expect references to  the source code (as in the linked duplicate) to suffice.

Comment: The "duplicate" is about the max string  length of a **single** argument from argv supported by the OS, not about how xargs determine how many arguments it could fit in a single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is `sysconf(_SC_ARG_MAX)`, including the environment strings and 2048 bytes of headroom. That's the maximum length of the actual strings + the separating null bytes, not the number of arguments. This is from GNU `xargs`' [source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/xargs/xargs.c?id=e3a1254e5c959d4aa1d2ffb2ae95672bbdaec567#n464):

> ```
>       /* IEEE Std 1003.1, 2003 specifies that the combined argument and
>        * environment list shall not exceed {ARG_MAX}-2048 bytes.  It also
>        * specifies that it shall be at least LINE_MAX.
>        */
>       long val;
> #ifdef _SC_ARG_MAX
>       val = sysconf (_SC_ARG_MAX);
>       if (val > 0)
>         {
>           assert (val > XARGS_POSIX_HEADROOM);
>           /* Note that val can in fact be greater than ARG_MAX
>            * and bc_ctl.arg_max can also be greater than ARG_MAX.
>            */
>           bc_ctl.arg_max = smaller_of (bc_ctl.arg_max,
>                                        (size_t)val-XARGS_POSIX_HEADROOM);
> ```

That is then clamped to 128k in [`bc_use_sensible_arg_max()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/buildcmd.c?id=e3a1254e5c959d4aa1d2ffb2ae95672bbdaec567#n534), but which could be increased via the `-s` option:

> ```
> void
> bc_use_sensible_arg_max (struct buildcmd_control *ctl)
> {
> #ifdef DEFAULT_ARG_SIZE
>   enum { arg_size = DEFAULT_ARG_SIZE };
> #else
>   enum { arg_size = (128u * 1024u) };
> #endif
> ```

Both the limit calculation and the clamping are the same for `find -exec ... {} +`; the code from above is duplicating the logic from [`bc_get_arg_max()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/buildcmd.c?id=e3a1254e5c959d4aa1d2ffb2ae95672bbdaec567#n414) and [`bc_init_controlinfo()`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/buildcmd.c?id=e3a1254e5c959d4aa1d2ffb2ae95672bbdaec567#n481), the latter of which is called with a `headroom` argument of 2048 from both `find/parser.c` and `xargs/xargs.c`.

GNU xargs also has a `--show-limits` option.

Comment: Well, thanks, wasn't aware of that parameter. That also means that by default the system defined limit is more a character length than an argument count limit, right?

Comment: exactly, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Note that the size of the current environment (all environment variables' names and values, possibly also including terminating nul-characters) also plays into this. See e.g. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html

Comment: That's already  mentioned that in the first line of my answer.