# Live tail from different folders with inclusion and exclusion of files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tail

I want to live `tail` from three different folders with certain files included & excluded.
**Folder 1:**

- Path: /var/www/app/var/log/
- Exclude only: file1.log & file2.log

**Folder 2:**

- Path: /var/log/web/log/
- Include only: error.log

**Folder 3:**

- Path: /var/log/service/log/
- Include only: app1.error.log & app2.error.log

How would I tail from three different folders with inclusion and exclusion of some files in one `tail` command?

```
tail -f ???
```

Tried so far

```
tail -f /var/www/app/var/log/!(file1,file2).log /var/log/web/log/error.log /var/log/service/log/{app1,app2}.log
```

But this doesn't work. I feel need to use `find` + `tail`

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @NasirRiley Updated my hit n trials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1634252/432690) to [your not-that-different question on SU](https://superuser.com/q/1634008/432690) to create three `find` commands that will find the files you're after. Then:

```
{ find … -print0 ; find … -print0 ; find … -print0 ; } | xargs -r -0 tail -F
```

Notes:

- `-F` because of this: [*How to do a `tail -f` of log rotated files?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22698/108618)
- `find` commands run just once. If a new file appears whose name would have been matched but didn't exist at the time, then `tail` will ignore it. In other words: when `tail` starts all of its arguments are fixed, the file-to-be is not among them.
- If the results form `find`s exceed [the limit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/472387/108618) then `xarg` will run more than one `tail` (by default not in parallel though). Certainly you don't want this. Hopefully your `find`s will find a reasonable number of files and the limit will not be exceeded.
- `find -print0` and `xargs -r -0` are not portable. You tagged [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu); in Ubuntu they will work.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Not sure how effective is the pipeline with `exec` command instead of `xargs`

Answer (score 0):

Tail all of the files you want... output each tail to a file... tail the new file.

tail -f /var/log/large.log > ~/full.log && tail -f /var/log/medium.log > ~/full.log && tail  -f ~/full.log

you can run it as one command but it looks a lil funky at first... but you could run it in another tty if you wanted and just tail the full log where you want it to look good.

Comment: you cant run it with the && sorry, you have to run it with a singular & or a nohup.

Comment: the && will wait until the first tail is done...